# Performant but memory efficient C hash map

Tags: c

I'm looking for a performant but also memory efficient C hash map implementation (or whatever you want to call it). Performance is slightly more important than memory use.

I would prefer a implementation which is MIT licensed or was put into the public domain.

Answer (score 5):

#### khash

A few C hash table/map libraries exist but, based on your requirements, the only one that I know you could try is [khash](https://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/programs/), by [Attractive Chaos](https://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/). It's part of [klib](https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib), a standalone and lightweight C library.

Essentially **khash is a fast and light-weighted hash table library in C** (implemented as a **C macro**, which can also help the performance).

It's released under the **MIT** licence as clearly reported in the [header file](http://attractivechaos.awardspace.com/khash.h.html) containing the actual implementation.

Comment: Although the author’s focus does not seem to be speed ("I would rather trade speed a bit for smaller memory.") it looks promising. I will give it a try.